# mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent have no effect in QGrapicsView in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I try to use `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` , but they don't work , I hope there is simpler way than using `eventFilter`

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView

class Window(QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setGeometry(400, 50, 800, 700)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(-180, -90, 360, 180)
        view = QGraphicsView(scene)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(view)
        view.scale(1,-1)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print('pressed')

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print('moving')
        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        print('released')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: If you don't want to use an event filter, then subclass the widget (QGraphicsView, in your case) and override those event handlers for it.

Comment: @musicamante, I used this way before and worked but now I don't want to create  another subclass , I want only one class for widget

Comment: The only other option is to overwrite event handlers with a custom function: `view.mousePressEvent = self.viewMousePress` `def viewMousePress(self, event):` `...`. But I *strongly* advise you to avoid that: 1. you will most certainly need to call the default event handler, which is **extremely** important for complex widgets (like QGraphicsView, which **must** call the base implementation in order to pass mouse events to the scene), so you need a reference to the widget; 2. it will complicate things unnecessarily, possibly resulting in unexpected behavior and bugs that are hard to track.

Comment: "Monkey patching" instance functions (especially event handlers) must always be done when it **does** make sense, which is when: 1. the overridden functions are simple enough to justify avoiding a subclass; 2. you really, ***REALLY*** know what you're doing. Also, PyQt uses function caching, so it *must* be done before the default implementation is called, otherwise it will never work. "I don't want another subclass" alone is not a sufficient reason. Subclassing is a basic concept of OOP, it's not meant to make "less code", but to make *smart* code that is also easy to understand and debug.